# mySql equivalent Sqlserver statement with COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I´m not finding ways to convert the following Sqlserver statement to mySql. I will be using that for a paging logic to view data:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) over (order by (SELECT NULL)) as CN, 
       Id,
       DateTime
FROM   MzMesDb.SysLog
WHERE  Deleted='F' order by id asc LIMIT 0,3;
```

The idea is to get that result from a table with 1000 rows where Deleted='F':

```
CN    Id    DateTime
1000  1  Data
1000  2  Data
1000  3  Data
```

So, it will return me the total number of rows and the 3 selected rows.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Confused, what are you trying to do with `count`?

Comment: You want to see wich IDs has 1000 rows where Deleted='F' is that it?

Comment: Andrew: This is to fill a grid objects. Count will return me the number of objects returned. Sometimes I will add a LIMIT clause to page the grid view.

Comment: Jorge: No. I wanna get the total row count of the selected fields with this condition. This is the normal SELECT condition, but when paging to grid I will add LIMIT clause. I will change the example.

Comment: Oracle is solved. Needs just mySql solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't the following solve this:

```
SELECT (select COUNT(*) from MzMesDb.SysLog) as CN, 
       Id,
       DateTime
FROM   MzMesDb.SysLog
WHERE  Deleted='F' 
order by id asc 
LIMIT 0,3;
```